# Find angle between 2 vectors (inner products)

Tags: inner-products

3. For complex vector spaces, i.e. vector spaces with scalars from the field $C $of complex
   numbers, inner products must have slightly different properties.

To see why, consider the
following vectors in $C^2$
:
$u = (1 + i, 2 − i)$, $ v = (2 − 3i, 4 + i)$
.

(a) Show that the usual dot product for $R^2$
fails to produce a real positive result for $<u, u>$.

(b) For this reason, we define the inner product for $C^
2$ as
 $<u, v> = \overline u_1v_1 + \overline u_2v_2$
where $\overline u$ denotes the complex conjugate of u.
Show that using this inner product $<u, u>$ is now real and positive. However show that
the symmetry axiom
$<u, v>$ = $<v, u>$ is now not satisfied. For this reason, the symmetry axiom for complex inner product
spaces becomes:
$<u, v>$ = complex conjugate of($<v, u>$)
which reduces to the usual axiom for real vector spaces.

(c) The angle θ between two vectors u and v is defined by ||u||||v|| cos θ = R(< u, v >),
where R(< u, v >) denotes the real part of the inner product. Find the angle between
u and v.

I've posted the entire question to give a background of it. Questions (a) and (b) are relatively easy and straightforward but how would one approach question (c)?

Answer (score 1):

One approaches this problem by doing exactly what it says. Calculate these values:
$$\|u\| = \sqrt{\langle u, u \rangle} = \sqrt{\bar u_1 u_1 + \bar u_2 u_2}$$
$$\|v\| = \sqrt{\langle v, v \rangle} = \sqrt{\bar v_1 v_1 + \bar v_2 v_2}$$
$$\langle u, v \rangle = \bar u_1 v_1 + \bar u_2 v_2$$

Next take the real part of the last one and divide it by the other two. That ratio is $\cos \theta$. Take the inverse cosine, and you're done.